# SQL Queries + DataTable + GridView

Tags: c#, sql, gridview, datatable

I need to read data from a SQL database and create the following result in a table:

```
DATABASE
=========
Server, Site Name, Status
001, Site 1, Down
002, Site 1, Up
003, Site 2, Up
004, Site 2, Down
001, Site 3, Up
005, Site 4, Down
```

- Site 1: it is present in 2 servers (001, 002)
- Site 2: it is present in 2 servers (003, 004)
- Site 3: It is present in only 1 server (001)
- Site 4: It is present in only 1 server (005)

RESULT:

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

SITE NAME 1  = 1 long column

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

SERVER 1 = Column 1 || SERVER 2 = Column 2

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

SITE NAME 2  = 1 long column

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

SERVER 1 = Column 1 || SERVER 2 = Column 2

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

Here is my C# code

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("my connection");
string SqlCon = "SELECT distinct(Site_Name) as SN FROM TABLE;";
using (myConnection)
{
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCon, myConnection);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da1.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) //IS THIS CORRECT?
    {
       string SqlCon2 = "SELECT * FROM LIVEWEBSITES WHERE Site_Name='" + dr["SN"].ToString() + "';";

       //Crete the table and populate it here

       if Status==Down then bgcolor of the cell = RED
       else bgcolor = GREEN

    }             

    MyGridView.DataSource = dt;
    MyGridView.DataBind();
}
```

First SQL Query was to select only the sites distinctively

Then with that information I do another SQL Query to select all the info and populate the table accordingly

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe LINQ would be better to achieve what I need? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a `DataContext` or `DbContext`. You basically map your database to your code. Then you can take advantage of using LINQ.

For instance if you had a Students table and StudentInfo table you could do something like this:

```
public class MyContext : DataContext
{
    public Table<Student> Students { get { return GetTable<Student>(); } }
    public Table<StudentInfo> StudentInfo { get { return GetTable<StudentInfo>(); } }
    public MyContext(string ConnString) : base(ConnString) {}
}

[Table(Name = "dbo.Students")]
public class Student
{
    [Column(IsPrimary = true, Name = "StudentId", IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "int Not Null IDENTITY")]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table(Name = "dbo.StudentInfo")]
public class StudentInfo
{
    [Column(IsPrimary = true, Name = "StudentInfoId", IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "int Not Null IDENTITY")]
    public int StudentInfoId { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "StudentId")]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }  // FK
    [Column(Name = "Address")]
    public string Address{ get; set; }
}

// a method somewhere
public void StudentLookup(string name)
{
    var MyContext context = new MyContext(connString);
    var student = context.Students.Single(x => x.Name == name)
    var StudentInfo = context.StudentInfo.Where(x => x.StudentId == student.StudentId);
}
```

This is one option, but I would recommend using Entity Framework with Code First Migration